# How to handle ConstraintViolationException in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java-ee-6

I'm trying ConstraintViolationException and I created a simple constraint Email and implemented the validator for it:

```
EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Email, String> { }
```

My problem is when I call persist from entityManager, it doesn't catch the exception. I looked at ConstraintViolationException and found out that ancestor class is RuntimeException so it's unchecked but I'm confused because I saw a lot of articles catching the same exception.

Anyone has any comment and workaround?

Comment: Why do you think you can't catch a runtime exception? You can. The entity manager won't catch it for you though. The whole point of a constraint is to throw an exception is it's violated.

Comment: Yes, I forgot I need to flush it manually which is not a good idea. Might have to settle with custom validator. Or do you have any solution or work around on this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have to flush what, to do what? What is the problem that you're trying to solve? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link solved my problem: [Catch PersistenceException or ConstraintViolationException in JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742000/catch-persistenceexception-or-constraintviolationexception-in-jboss-as-7)

And then as a workaround I created an email validator and add an f:validator to the field I'm validating.

```
@FacesValidator("emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator {

public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {

    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages",
            Locale.ENGLISH);

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
        return;
    } else {
        try {
            InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(
                    value.toString());
            emailAddr.validate();
        } catch (AddressException ex) {
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage();
            String message = resourceBundle
                    .getString("message.error.invalidEmail");
            message = MessageFormat.format(message,
                    getLabel(context, component));
            facesMessage.setDetail(message);
            facesMessage.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

            throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);
        }
    }

}
```

Add this inside the field you are validating.

```
<f:validator for="#{cc.attrs.id}_text" validatorId="emailValidator"></f:validator>
```